# Field Value Mapping QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, field-mapping

I am wondering if there is a way to do field value maps that are filtered based on another attribute field?  I know how to associate value maps, but not that are connected to another field.

I have two fields in a table Type and Subtype.  Type will have three values: Trees, Bushes, and Flowers.

The Subtypes will have different values.  ie:

```
 Subtype for trees would be conifer and deciduous
 Subtype for flowers would be roses, daisies, and sunflowers
 Subtype for bushes would be blueberry, raspberry, and blackberry
```

What I want is when Trees is selected from Type, only conifer and deciduous are available from subtype; etc...

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at the moment, but this is a planned for 2.1 or 2.2.

You only option at the moment is a custom form with some Python logic to handle that kind of thing.

Comment: Hey Nathan, do you know of any resources that would show an example of building and using custom forms for this?

Comment: Are you in 1.8 or 1.9 (2.0)?

Comment: I'll point you to my own blog posts on the subject http://nathanw.net/2011/09/05/qgis-tips-custom-feature-forms-with-python-logic/ and http://nathanw.net/2012/03/30/custom-qgis-feature-forms-value-binding/

Comment: and a video I did https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z84GMcQV3EM