# Limiting available values in dropdown field of QGIS form according to value selected in previous field?

Tags: qgis, postgis, expression, field-mapping, value-list

I'm building a rather complex entry form for a layer stored in a PostGIS database. I am following this usage scenario:

On several occasions I have dropdown fields which lets the user select a type of artefact (populated through value relation to another table in a database), followed immediately with the field letting them select a subtype (also populated through value relation to another table in a database). I would like a choice of subtypes in the dropdown to be limited by the previous selection of a type.

For example, if type "ceramics" is selected the subtype dropdown needs to be limited to only options with a key value from 1 to 10.

If type "metals" is selected the subtype dropdown needs to be limited to only options with a key value from 11 to 20.

And so on.

I feel relatively fluent in SQL and qgis expression builder, and i would guess this could be achieved trough filter expression option on value relation widget, but I wouldn't know how to invoke the values from a form which is currently being filled.

I suspect some python code is needed? - I'm not fluent in python but I guess I could adapt an example of code to my needs by renaming the fields etc.

Question is similar to [Field Value Mapping QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69349/field-value-mapping-qgis) but the answers there didnt point me out in directions I could apply with my current knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a table which as all the values you need and add to your map. Create a relationship (Project>properties>relations). Then when building your form in the edit widget properties, select value relation
Here you can filter what is displayed (ie if x then show values where filterField = y)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I have tested this feature in 2.10 and i have to note this solves a part of the problem: the dropdown is filtered according to the values in the filter column. But i have to note that the filter value itself (which is a category of artefact) is not recorded - it either requires me to write a database trigger to fill it in or create another dropdown to select it (and that is very awkward and redundant from a user perspective). 
I dont wont to sound picky but i would much prefer a solution which invokes a value entered in a separate dropdown.

Comment: Hmm this is kind of I what I am looking for have you found the way create such a database trigger or not? Please let me know I am kind also in a bind here.

Answer (score 0):

Get the plugin [Form Value Relation](http://www.itopen.it/a-new-qgis-plugin-allows-dynamic-filtering-of-values-in-forms/).  I've created a smart form with cascading drop-down boxes with this plugin.